# CodeIgniter routes are not working

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I've defined following route in config file as follows.

```
$route['apartments/(:any)'] = 'apartments/view/$1';
```

If I give `http://localhost/apartment_advertisement/apartments/shobha_complex` like this in url it works perfectly fine.

If I give `http://localhost/apartment_advertisement/apartments/shobha_complex/abcd/abcd` like this in url it goes to the same page as above. So I needed error page for this url. Please help me how to control these urls?. The work would be more appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean display an 404-not-found error when request URL has an unwanted "tail"? You can modify `(:any)` to restrict accepted string. It's simple:

```
$route['apartments/(\w+)'] = 'apartments/view/$1';
```